# Pandas apply method on a column only when conditions are met

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to use `df.apply` to a DataFrame column.

The df represents hierarchical biological classifications.

[Dataframe for biological data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g6XQh.png)

I want to show the relevant classification depending on if the data exists within the column.
I have written a function that should do this:

```
def condition(data):
    for i in range(len(data)):
        if data.G[i] and data.Taxonomy[i]:
            return(data.G[i] + " " +data.Taxonomy[i])
        elif data.G[i] and not data.Taxonomy[i]:
            return(data.G[i])
        elif not data.G[i] and not data.Taxonomy[i]:
            return(data.F[i])
        elif data.O[i] and not data.G[i] and not data.Taxonomy[i]:
            return(data.O[i])
        elif data.C[i] and not data.O[i] and not data.G[i] and not data.Taxonomy[i]:
            return(data.C[i])
        elif data.P[i] and not data.O[i] and not data.G[i] and not data.Taxonomy[i]:
            return(data.P[i])
        elif data.k[i] and not data.P[i] and not data.O[i] and not data.G[i] and not data.Taxonomy[i]:
            return(data.k[i])
```

I have attempted to apply this function to the dataframe to output an additional column which shows the data after it has gone through condition():

```
data['name']=data.apply(lambda x: condition(data), axis = 1)
```

I receive the output of

[Output after df.apply](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L3Pzn.png)

Where the outcome repeats itself instead of applying the function per row.

How can I apply this function so it gives the desired output?

Comment: Apply is not the way to go, see first answer  in the duplicate link with `np.select`

Answer (score 0):

You must apply lambda on x not the data:

```
data['name']=data.apply(lambda x: condition(x), axis = 1)
```

instead of

```
data['name']=data.apply(lambda x: condition(data), axis = 1)
```